# Android Studio sun.font.CompositeFont cannot be cast to sun.font.PhysicalFont

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I keep getting this error when trying to run Android Studio 2.2.3 on two different Ubuntu Computers. One running 14.04 Trusty and the other 16.04 Xenial.

It runs the splash screen, the loading bar gets to the end, and then it sits there and this error is shown in the console.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0 
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@2077d4de for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so 
Found library resource at jar:file:/home/me/Downloads/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so 
Trying /home/me/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna3820816485682346846.tmp 
Found jnidispatch at /home/me/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna3820816485682346846.tmp 
[   9485]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /home/me/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.  
[   9618]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - File /home/me/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.  
[   9994]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.font.CompositeFont cannot be cast to sun.font.PhysicalFont  
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.font.CompositeFont cannot be cast to sun.font.PhysicalFont 
       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:204) 
       at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52) 
       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311) 
       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756) 
       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) 
       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) 
       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) 
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) 
       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726) 
       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366) 
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201) 
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) 
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) 
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) 
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) 
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.font.CompositeFont cannot be cast to sun.font.PhysicalFont 
       at sun.font.CompositeFont.doDeferredInitialisation(CompositeFont.java:293) 
       at sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(CompositeFont.java:360) 
       at sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.getSlotMapper(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:114) 
       at sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.convertToGlyph(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:124) 
       at sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.charToGlyph(CompositeGlyphMapper.java:162) 
       at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getCodePointAdvance(CompositeStrike.java:158) 
       at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.handleCharWidth(FontDesignMetrics.java:416) 
       at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getLatinCharWidth(FontDesignMetrics.java:425) 
       at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.stringWidth(FontDesignMetrics.java:476) 
       at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.stringWidth(SwingUtilities2.java:403) 
       at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabelImpl(SwingUtilities.java:1005) 
       at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(SwingUtilities.java:890) 
       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicGraphicsUtils.getPreferredButtonSize(BasicGraphicsUtils.java:282) 
       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getPreferredSize(BasicButtonUI.java:376) 
       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getMinimumSize(BasicButtonUI.java:366) 
       at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1744) 
       at java.awt.GridLayout.minimumLayoutSize(GridLayout.java:390) 
       at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1848) 
       at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1832) 
       at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1746) 
       at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:1117) 
       at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:916) 
       at java.awt.GridBagLayout.minimumLayoutSize(GridBagLayout.java:750) 
       at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1848) 
       at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1832) 
       at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1746) 
       at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(BorderLayout.java:663) 
       at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1848) 
       at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1832) 
       at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1746) 
       at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(BorderLayout.java:673) 
       at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1848) 
       at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1832) 
       at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1746) 
       at javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout.minimumLayoutSize(JRootPane.java:944) 
       at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1848) 
       at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1832) 
       at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1746) 
       at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(BorderLayout.java:663) 
       at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1848) 
       at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1832) 
       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame.<init>(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:109) 
       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.createFrame(FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.java:29) 
       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:171) 
       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:340) 
       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:200) 
       ... 16 more 
[   9998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 2.2.3  Build #AI-145.3537739  
[   9998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_76-release  
[   9998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM  
[   9998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o  
[   9998]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux  
[   9999]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:   
^C[  13652]   WARN - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 130
```

Comment: `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning` you probably should use oracle java for android

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144120 linked to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144124

Comment: That issue said the Helvetica font file was the issue. I hid the folder "mv to .helvetica" and the IDE started no problem. It mentions that the issue is fixed in jetbrains so hopefully that will make it into Android Studio in due time.

Comment: This really seems to be a font-related bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144124 in OpenJDK, so as a workaround until the fix is available everywhere, one can use another JDK or move away the offending font (all of `$HOME/.fonts` in my case, as it is not trivial to find the offending font). This bug aside, I have no problems using OpenJDK 8 to run Android Studio.

Comment: OpenJDK issue. [track](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163717)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, thank you to those who commented on the question, your input solved my problem. I just wanted to add a proper answer.

As found in the several track links in the question comments, the problem seems to be related to the Helvetica font file from a Mac. From the link:

> The problem is a bad font: /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Helvetica.ttf
>
> It was copied from OS X machine and is attached.
>
> When the font is removed, the problem is resolved.

It is claimed to be fixed, and the IDEA runs for me. Just have to wait for Google to integrate the changes into its Android Studio version I suspect.

Comment: Please flag your question as answered so other people can know it is resolved, thanks!

Comment: for me it must be another font from `$HOME/.fonts` -- how to I find the offending font?